# knockout optionsText / optionsValue bindings won't work

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

Why does this binding fail with a "value not found" exception?

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.arr, optionsValue: key, optionsText: value"></select>
```

The options array's data is this:

```
ko.observableArray ([ 
  {key: 'foo', value: '1'}, 
  {key: 'bar', value: '2'}
])
```

*I already solved my own problem but laying down a StackOverflow breadcrumb trail so others won't waste their time like I did trying to figure this out. ;-)*

Answer (score 3):

Quotes are required around property names used in optionsText and optionsValue. Like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.arr, optionsValue: 'key', optionsText: 'value'"></select>
```

I'd assumed that:

1. The `options` binding created a new binding context like `with` and `foreach` do
2. The optionsValue and optionsText worked like the `text` binding where you can just specify the property name and KO magically binds to the properties

Both assumptions were wrong, as I realized after an hour of stepping through the KO sources trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Arrrrgh!

Instead, if you're not using a function to pull out the value or text for each option, and you want to access a property instead, you need to enclose the property name in quotes. This is shown in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) if you read the example code carefully enough. Which I didn't. ;-(